# In Mac gfortran 4.7.2, isatty(6) does not work

Tags: fortran, gfortran

In Mac 10.8.2, use gfortran 4.7.2 to compile the following code:

```
program test
    write(*, *) isatty(6)
end program test
```

The program just not response and not return. Any idea?

Comment: Do you really need the isatty() call, which is a GNU extension to Fortran? If your purpose is to get the unit number of the standard output, you could use the parameter `output_unit` from the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.

Comment: Yes, I need it. Because I need to judge whether the program output is redirected to a file or not. I have added some color codes on the output, so if redirected, the ugly color codes will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you get no output, it works fine for me with gfortran 4.7.2 on Linux. You could try whether writing your own interface to C's `isatty` makes any difference:

```
program test
  implicit none

  interface
    function my_isatty(fd) bind(C, name = 'isatty')
      use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int
      integer(c_int)        :: my_isatty
      integer(c_int), value :: fd
    end function
  end interface

  ! Standard output should be at 1 in C:
  print*, my_isatty(1) 
end program test
```

I get the following output:

```
$ ./a.out
    1
$ ./a.out > b && cat b
    0
```

Comment: It works on Mac 10.8.2 with gfortran 4.7.2! Thanks! It may be a bug in gfortran?

Comment: Well, I don't know what gfortran does exactly; I would expect it to call the same C function as in my answer. You could also consult the gfortran developers about this, perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: Apparently, gfortran's `isatty` comes from its own library, and the C interface calls the C library function directly. The entries I get in the program's symbol table are `_gfortran_isatty_l4@@GFORTRAN_1.0` and `isatty@@GLIBC_2.2.5`, respectively.